# Passing the name of the link when clicked

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

```
<a href="process.html">cholera</a>
```

I want to pass `cholera` to `process.html` onClick. Is there any way to do that in HTML?

If no, PHP scripts are also most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pure HTML, only by pre-populating the link with the correct value:

```
<a href="process.html?name=cholera">cholera</a>
```

for anything that fetches the link's contents automatically, you would have to use JavaScript. This is comparably easy to do in jQuery. (**Update**: @James M presents a simple and nice non-jQuery solution in his answer.)

On the receiving end, though, you are going to need some kind of server language (or JavaScript) to do anything with the passed argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="process.html?foo=cholera">cholera</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $values = array('cholera', 'chlamydia'); // dynamic
  foreach($values as $value) echo '<a href="process.php?value=' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>' . '<br />';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $value = !isset($_GET['value']) ? 'none' : $_GET['value'];
?>
Value received: <?php echo $value; ?>
</body>
</html>
```